# Настройки адресов в Spring Security игнорируются

Tags: java, spring, сервер, kotlin, spring-security

**Дано:**

Проект на `spring`. Подключена БД, в ней лежат юзеры, можно их запросить по адресу `http://localhost:8080/users/all`.

**Задача:**

Требовать логина при запросе юзеров, но пускать в корень.

**Проблема:**

Не получается никак настроить свободный доступ к `/`. Подключил `security` - теперь все пути выводят форму логина, куда я могу с данными юзеров из БД залогиниться, но никакие из испробованных способов не дают свободно на рут ходить.

**Вопрос:**

<s>почему такое простое действие сложнее создания БД и АПИ к ней</s>- как мне открыть рут для всех запросов?

В данный момент выглядит так конфигурация:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfiguration : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var dataSource: DataSource

    @Autowired
    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder() = NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance() as NoOpPasswordEncoder

    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth
                .jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
    }
}
```

Пробовал настраивать пути по всякому, например так, но, кажется, всё что я пишу просто игнорируется:

```
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .anonymous().disable()
            .antMatcher("/users/**").authorizeRequests()

    //и как только я не пробовал, ничего не меняется
}
```

Пробовал специальную штуку для игнорирования - она тоже не работает

```
override fun configure(webSecurity: WebSecurity) {
    webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/")
}
```

или

```
override fun configure(webSecurity: WebSecurity) {
    webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/**")
}
```

---

**UPD_0:**

Вот [репозиторий со всем проектом](https://github.com/mohaxspb/springSecurityExample): для запуска и работы надо поставить `postgresql` и создать там под юзером `postgres` с паролем `testtest` БД с именем `springbootdb` - далее при запуске в БД создана будет таблица с юзерами и туда будет добавлен юзер, под коим можно логиниться с логином `test@test.ru` и паролем `password`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75143/discussion-on-question-by-----spring-security-).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, тут всё очень важно было(((

Comment: Предлагаете восстановить? Может все–таки ответом?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, [meta-tag:модераторский-произвол]!

Comment: Да, собственно мне таки помогли я как раз хотел просить в ответ написать)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас были 2 проблемы.

1. У вас **@CompnentScan** был настроен так чтобы игнорировал все классы аннотированные **@Configuration**

   `excludeFilters = [ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = [Configuration::class])]`, это надо было удалить.
2. Не были нужные зависимости для настройки *Security*, надо было добавить

   `compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"`

и собственно настройка самого spring-security:

```
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/users/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, вы мой герой! =) Правда, после того как это заработало у меня отвалилась авторизация( Требовать стала полей в таблице юзеров и искать ещё доп. таблицу с ролями, хотя раньше и без этого всё работало) Но это я уже сам разберусь. А аннотация у меня появилась, т.к. без неё проект просто не запускался на каком-то этапе экспериментов)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вам там надо переписать часть. у вас есть `spring-data` его и используйте для работы с базой, это удобнее и быстрее. Для решение вашей проблемы можете посмотреть сюда, проблем переписать на котлин не должно быть https://hellokoding.com/registration-and-login-example-with-spring-security-spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-hsql-jsp/

Comment: Имеете в виду, что не надо писать начальные данные в БД в скриптах, а делать это где-то программно? За ссылку спасибо, изучу)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вместо скриптов, spring может сам создать за вас базу, смотрите `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto`. А вообще я про то что эта смесь плоха использовать 2 разных подхода работы с базой (spring-data & jdbc) одновременно. На этом все, а то опять придет злой модератор и удалит все)

Comment: Ого... Я думал, что `spring-data` использует `jdbc` для работы... Разные у меня подходы это SQL скрипты? Или то, что я вообще JDBC использую? Я запутался(((

Comment: А модераторы они да, злые все)

Comment: Ну вы просто добавили как зависимость jdbc-driver для spring-data и все остальные операции делаете через spring-data. У вас авторизация реализована через jdbc, best practices это написать свой user-service для авторизации

Comment: Хм... Т.е. вы имеете в виду, что один раз подключив драйвер мне не надо его трогать и авторизации не DB отдавать в качестве источника `UserDetails`, но `userDetailsService`, который уже через репозиторий вытащит юзера при попытке авторизации? Коли так, то это круто) И все примеры с `jdbc` авторизацией надо удалить из интернетов)